# Using vtiger webserices to login with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have a problem with login to vtiger crm via jquery using webservices.
This is my code:

```js
function doLogin(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
    {  
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }else{ 
        }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://vtiger_path/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","json");
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The `xmlhttp.status` is always 0, so I don't get the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a cross-domain Ajax call (or not easily...)

Can't you use PHP ???

Here is a snippet :

HTML / JS part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

        var userName = 'admin';
        var webserviceUrl = 'http://vtiger_path/altaircrm/webservice.php';
        var action = "?operation=getchallenge&username=";

        var a = webserviceUrl+action+userName;

        $.ajax({
            url: "ws.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data:{'data':a},
            success: function(data) { alert(data); },
            error: function(data) { alert('Failed!'); },
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP part:

```
<?php
 $a = $_POST['data'];
 $json = file_get_contents($a);

  echo $json;
?>
```